# When I try two get elements in DOM with HTML and Xpath results undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

i was practicing with Xpath and I can't get the elements. My code is simple:

```
<html>
<script>

//get first div
var headings = document.evaluate('//h2', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

var res = headings.iterateNext()
while(res){
console.log(res);
var res = headings.iterateNext()
}

console.log(headings);

</script>
<body>
    <div>HI!!!</div>
    <h2> JOE </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This return undefined. I tried with every possible xpathExpression (Tested on firefox and chrome ). 
Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that i have to wait until the dom document is fully loaded.
Just tried this example and its works fine:

    <head>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetElements () {
                
    var headings = document.evaluate('//h2', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
    
    var res = headings.iterateNext()
    while(res){
    console.log(res);
    var res = headings.iterateNext()
    }
    
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="GetElements ()">
        <h2>ONE</h2>
        <h2>TWO</h2>
    </body>


Bye!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i have to wait until the dom document is fully loaded.
Just tried this example and its works fine:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetElements () {

var headings = document.evaluate('//h2', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

var res = headings.iterateNext()
while(res){
console.log(res);
var res = headings.iterateNext()
}

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetElements ()">
    <h2>ONE</h2>
    <h2>TWO</h2>
</body>
```

Bye!@